# Segmentation fault trying to show camera video feed. PyQt5

Tags: python, debugging, pyqt, raspberry-pi

I am working on a Raspberry Pi 3 V1.2 with Raspbian. My Problem is that sometimes my code works (a window opens and shows the camera feed) and sometimes it doesnt (Error is Segmentation fault). I have never experienced that code only works sometimes. I know the error happens when the compiler is at the startVid function. Anyone have a idea? Thanks already for the help.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore , QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QCamera, QCameraInfo, QMediaObject, QCameraViewfinderSettings, QCameraImageCapture
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QCameraViewfinder


class Camera(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent = QObject()):
        super(Camera, self).__init__(parent)
        self.cam = QCamera()
        self.caminfo = QCameraInfo(self.cam)
        self.camvfind = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.camvfindset = QCameraViewfinderSettings()
        self.cammode = self.cam.CaptureMode(1)
        self.camimgcap = QCameraImageCapture(self.cam)

    def iniCamera(self):
        print(self.caminfo.description())
        print(self.caminfo.availableCameras())

        if self.cam.isCaptureModeSupported(self.cammode):
            print("Capturemode supported")


    def startVid(self):

        self.camvfind.show()

        self.cam.setViewfinder(self.camvfind)

        self.cam.load()
        self.camvfindset.setResolution(1280,720)
        #print(self.cam.supportedViewfinderFrameRateRanges(self.camvfind))
        self.camvfindset.setMinimumFrameRate(15)

        self.cam.setCaptureMode(self.cammode)
        self.cam.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    cam = Camera()

    cam.iniCamera()

    cam.startVid()


    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I used gbd to learn more about the error. This was the output:

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/python3 qt.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x720a7470 (LWP 20003)]
[New Thread 0x716ff470 (LWP 20004)]

** (python3:19975): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
[New Thread 0x6ff00470 (LWP 20007)]
[New Thread 0x6f5ff470 (LWP 20008)]
[New Thread 0x6e6ab470 (LWP 20022)]
[Thread 0x6e6ab470 (LWP 20022) exited]
[New Thread 0x6e6ab470 (LWP 20023)]
[Thread 0x6e6ab470 (LWP 20023) exited]
Venus USB2.0 Camera
[<PyQt5.QtMultimedia.QCameraInfo object at 0x72fde030>]
Capturemode supported

Thread 1 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x7344b620 in platform_get_handle () from /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so
```

ok here the output of the command (gdb) bt:

```
(gdb) bt
0  0x733d4620 in platform_get_handle () from /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so
1  0x733c9f2c in eglCreateWindowSurface () from /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so
2  0x722e7004 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.so
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Comment: I wouldn't call `del cam` where you are. By doing that you're asking Python to delete the PyQt objects before you even start your GUI event loop. Try removing that line and seeing if it helps.

Comment: well i just tried some stuff, but it didnt work so i dont have del cam in my code anymore. I used psutil to display the memory usage in the code. but sadly the segmentation fault seems to happen on random. Sometimes when it shows 46528832 bytes it works and sometimes when its 49455104 bytes it doesnt.

Comment: Could you provide the version number of PyQt (sand also the version of QT5 that your PyQt is compiled against)?

Comment: QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.7.1 in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
and i installed pyqt5 with sudo apt-get install and this version is 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Did you try unloading the camera before you exit? Segmentation fault is caused by trying to read or write an illegal memory location.

unload will free all the resources allocated to the cam object.

Comment: Adding self.cam.unload() to startVid() did nothing, besides that now not even a window will pop up. I obviously googled the problem and i saw many people using `del` to deconstruct their code.